# Customize Devise SessionsController create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, passwords

I want to add a feature that will redirect a user with an expired password to the reset password page. 
My controller looks like this

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:user][:email].downcase)
    if user.password_expire?
      raw, enc = Devise.token_generator.generate(current_user.class,
                                               :reset_password_token)
      user.reset_password_token   = enc
      user.reset_password_sent_at = Time.now.utc
      user.save(validate: false)
      redirect_to edit_password_url(user, reset_password_token: raw)
    else
      self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
      set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in)
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      yield resource if block_given?
      respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    end
  end

end
```

When I debug with binding.pry at the top of the action, I find that current_user exists and user_signed_in? is true. How is it possible I'm signed in before the create method completes?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the security extension you don't need at all to take care of the implementation of password expiration.
And if you are not using it, you should check it out -  [devise_security_extension](https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension).

Answer (score 1):

Devise remembers the current user using cookies until they log out.

Just because they've hit your sign in route doesn't mean they're signed out.

#### Diving into Devise

Tracing the code in Devise to understand what happens we see:

**1. [Devise::SessionsController#create](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/873e49ab66d02b7c9ab5ea4c2fd7383965834917/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L13)**

```
class Devise::SessionsController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def create
    # ...
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    # ...
  end
end
```

**2. [Devise::Controllers::Helpers#sign_in](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/873e49ab66d02b7c9ab5ea4c2fd7383965834917/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L98)**

```
  def sign_in(resource_or_scope, *args)
    # ...
    if options[:bypass]
      warden.session_serializer.store(resource, scope)
    elsif warden.user(scope) == resource && !options.delete(:force)
      # Do nothing. User already signed in and we are not forcing it.
      true # <=== Here's the moment of truth
    else
    # ...
  end
```

#### Conclusion

- The user can hit your `sessions#create` when they're already logged in
- In this case the default Devise behaviour is to do nothing
- Not quite sure what you want to achieve above, but calling super might come in handy somewhere to resume the default Devise behaviour